# height not adjusting for UL and DIV container

Tags: css, html, height, overflow, html-lists

Anyone has any idea how to make this slider to adjust the height?

http://www.awesomeget.net/#steps-slider

right now the height is set in DIV "container", but if you remove the height then nothing gets displayed. It appears the UL element somehow doesn't give its height to the parent. i added overflow:hidden to the "steps-holder" and "slide-holder" which are the parent containers... and made sure this UL element is not floated....but still nothing changes..

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned above since the List Items are positioned absolutely, you won't be able to do this with just css unless you remove the "absolute" positioning. However you can do it with jQuery:

remove the height: 300px for div.container and add this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   tmpHeight = $(".slides li").height() + 46; // I added 46 to get to 330, but you should do this with padding in css or something
   $("div.container").css("height", tmpHeight + "px");

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your method, but it only set the height to the height of the first List item. I needed each LI have it's own height.
I wanted to build upon your suggestion and make it dynamic for each LI... then I realized there is was already an option for this feature in the slider!!! dang! The person who made the slider (http://nathansearles.com/loopedslider/) had already thought about it and the setting for it was in the loopedslider.js as autoHeight =  1 or false

Comment: I wouldn't have figured it out if it wasn't for your suggestion to do it in JQuery. Otherwise, I would have been stuck in CSS! Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

The ul and li elements within the div are positioned absolutely, which means they are removed from the normal flow, so the div they are contained in is not affected by their size. Removing the absolute positioning will fix the problem, though it might be the cause of others.

Answer (score 0):

In your `black.css` file on line 705 there is a `height` property set to all `a` elements of the slides. Remove that part for a start... then remove the `overflow: hidden` and `height` properties from the container with a class of `steps-holder`. I actually found no div with a class of `container` in your `steps-slider` block... please specify if it's a class. It's a bit misleading :)

If this is the effect you wish to achieve of course) http://clip2net.com/s/1Qyvr